# Repeat pageblocksection on commandbutton click

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, repeat, pageblocksection

I have a visualforce page and i'm going to add multiple Product into my custom object but where i am stuck is i am not able to set `<apex:repeat>` to my pageblocksection

I just want to repeat the `Pageblocksection` when user need to add multiple Product..

I tried but it's not getting me the expected result

**Visualforce :**

```
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">
    <apex:commandButton value="Add Product" action="{!addSection1}" reRender="qbp"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:outputPanel id="qbp">
    <div>
    <ul id="sortable">
    <apex:variable value="" var="foo" rendered="{!IF(lstSections1 = True, true, false)}">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
            <apex:repeat value="{!QBP}" var="q">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Product">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Select Product :" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!q.Product__c}" >
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="relatedInfo" action="{!retrieveproductInfo}" immediate="false"/>
                    </apex:inputField>
                        <apex:pageBlockSection id="relatedInfo">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!partNumber}" label="Part Number :"/>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Description}" label="Description :"/>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!q.Quantity__c}"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:actionRegion>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:repeat>
        </li>
    </apex:variable>
    </ul>
    </div>        
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: From your code its not clear what desired and actual result is. Maybe post some screenshots.

Comment: @RahulSharma only one pageblocksection is there and i am going to repeat that part only. hope it is clear now :)

Comment: It was clear, but from your code its not clear on what is not working. what have you tried so far?

Comment: i am sorry Rahul, my bad.. there are two Pageblocksection and i need to repeat first Parent section

Comment: Ok. let me edit my post with what i've tried

Comment: @RahulSharma Updated !! Can you please look into it and let me know what correction i need or what code i placed wrong

Comment: You can implement such functionality using wrapper class, Please check this blog post http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/12/adding-and-deleting-rows-dynamically-in.html

Comment: @SarojBera OK. i see the blog that you have provided, so this is not possible with repeat ?

Comment: @HSdev You can do with Apex repeat also. The approach is same.

Comment: the apex associated with button action `addSection1` is the key missing bit in your OP; use [edit] to amend